# wordpress php str_replace function with variables not quite there

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, str-replace

I'm pretty new to PHP so perhaps lacking some basics so here goes.

For WordPress I've a function for replacing some text from a TablePress table. The function worked fine when I used code along these lines:

```
 function replace_stuff($text) {

 if  (is_front_page() || is_page('2611') || is_child('2611'))  {

    $replace_magic = array(
        //text to search => text to replace
        'dog' => 'cat',
        'mouse' => 'elephant'
    );
}
$text = str_replace(array_keys( (array)$replace_magic), $replace_magic, $text);


return $text;
}

add_filter('tablepress_table_output', 'replace_stuff');
```

So in that example dog would be displayed on the frontend as cat & mouse as elephant.

But now I would like to complicate things & create the strings to replace by querying fields from all posts in a custom post type "drivers".

I have come up with something like this, with the aim of finding any text that matches the post title & replacing with text from a custom field (of all posts from my 'drivers' custom post type), but it doesn't do anything!

```
  function replace_stuff($text) {

  if (is_front_page() || is_page('2611') || is_child('2611') || get_post_type() == 'drivers') {

  query_posts('post_type=drivers');
   if (have_posts()) : 
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  $profilenat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'driver_nationality', true);
  $profiletitle = get_the_title();


    $replace_magic = array(
        //text to search => text to replace
        $profiletitle => $profilenat
    );

endwhile;
    endif;
}

$text = str_replace(array_keys( (array)$replace_magic), $replace_magic, $text);

return $text;
}

add_filter('tablepress_table_output', 'replace_stuff');
```

Could anyone advise me please?
Many thanks.

Comment: @Jamie `echo $text` and `print_r($replace_magic)` will be helpful if you could post them here as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I think you need to replace
$replace_magic = array(
with
$replace_magic[$profiletitle] = $profilenat

Currently, if everything else works, then for every driver you are completely replacing the contents of $replace_magic with a new array, which just has that driver's details. Instead you want to add a new item to the existing array.

Going further, with this sort of problem it can be really useful to do some quick debugging to help you narrow down where the problem might be. So here it would be useful to know if the problem is really with your str_replace, or if it's actually with the code above it.

[Debugging in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) is worth a read, and having done that you can use error_log to output some details to debug.log inside your wp-content directory.

Before your str_replace, doing
error_log(print_r($replace_magic));
Would tell you if your query loop has worked as you intended or not.
If it hasn't, you might then put a log statement inside the loop. This will tell you if the  loop contents are being executed at all (in which case the problem is with your code inside the loop), or not (in which case the problem may be with your query).

Additionally, if you haven't already I would recommend checking the [WordPress Codex on query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). query_posts manipulates the main Wordpress query, and may give you some really unexpected results used inside a filter like this. At least consider WP_Query - and check the note about wp_reset_posts.

Hope that helps - apologies if some of it is stuff you already considered, but as you mentioned you're quite new to PHP I hope it's useful.

Comment: Thanks, you were right to debug - I found the $profilenat variable was undefined.

I replaced with a shorter call I have a function for in my wordpress theme.

$drivernat = get_custom_field('driver_nationality', TRUE);

this works


----the custom field function is:

    function get_custom_field($key, $echo = FALSE) {
 global $post;
 $custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
 if ($echo == FALSE) return $custom_field;
 echo $custom_field;
    }